# Rails Helper renders array, not html

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, helper, partials, content-for

If I call `render_slider_items(["a.png", "b.png", "c.png"])` my webpage shows the array  `["a.png", "b.png", "c.png"]`, not the html.

```
module ApplicationHelper
 def render_slider_items(filenames)
    filenames.each do |filename|
      content_tag(:div, class: "col-md-3") do 
        tag("img", src: "assets/#{filename}")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

What would cause this?

UPDATE - Solution-

```
      def render_slider_items(filenames)
        filenames.collect do |filename|
          content_tag(:div, class: "col-md-3") do 
            tag("img", src: "assets/#{filename}")
          end
        end
      end.join().html_safe
```

Comment: What does `each` return? What does a Ruby method return?

Comment: fillenames is an array of filenames, so the .each returns a string of each file name.

Comment: So the problem with your method is that it was returning what `each` returned so it was just a complicated way of saying `return filenames`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you're calling this like this

```
#some_file.html.erb
<%= render_slider_items(["a.png", "b.png", "c.png"]) %>
```

If that's the case the reason this is happening to you is because the `.each` method [returns the array](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html) it's iterating over. You'd be better off doing something like this:

```
module ApplicationHelper
 def render_slider_items(filenames)
    filenames.collect do |filename|
      content_tag(:div, class: "col-md-3") do 
        tag("img", src: "assets/#{filename}")
      end
    end
  end.join.html_safe
end
```

Comment: slight improvement. now it returns an array of <div> <img>'s instead of just rendering the html.

Comment: I also needed to add .join().html_safe